# Hiding an item using ngClass expression in Ionic using Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm trying to apply `ion-hide` [class](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#element-display) to `ion-col`. For some reason, it is not applying when I try to use `ngClass`. Could anyone please help?

```
<ion-col [ngClass]="{ 'ion-hide': !flag }">
  <div>Content</div>
</ion-col>
```

Comment: Try to check if `flag` is being set with the desired value. Also, if you're using `OnPush` strategy for change detection, it may need some manual work to make it work. There's nothing wrong with your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax:

```
<ion-col [class.ion-hide]="!flag">
  <div>Content</div>
</ion-col>
```